# Are there "free actions" in D&D 5e?

Tags: dnd-5e, actions

Earlier editions (i.e. 4th Edition) had Free Actions that included talking, etc. I can't find any mention of Free Actions in the 5th Edition Players Handbook (I don't own a Dungeon Masters Guide). However, in a 5th Edition compatible OGL manual from TPK Games "Fifth Edition Feats"; several of the feats mention using Free Actions.

Is there an "Official" mechanic/rule for Free Actions in D&D 5th Edition?

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer. I'll note you've done so pretty quickly. While *I* think my answer's great, please know that if a better answer comes along you have the ability to unaccept mine and accept that one.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

### PHB p.190: "Other actions on your turn"

> Your turn can include a variety of flourishes that require neither your action nor your move....

Then follows some descriptions of talking, gestures, interacting with objects. There's a sidebar that provides an exemplary, though not exhaustive, list of what those actions/interactions might be.

(These paragraphs are not included in the SRD, though they're obliquely hinted at by one sentence in Use an Object: "you normally interact with an object while doing something else.")